# how to automatically select max value in a list.append - python

Tags: python, machine-learning, max

I am doing a machine learning project where I need to select the highest cv_results value of classifier. How do I automatically select the highest value of classifier after all the values are calculated and stored in a single variable, cv_results?

```
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))

maxval = models[0] # initialize max to first element
results = []
names = []
storeresults = []
for name, model in models:

kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_tr, Y_tr, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
results.append(cv_results)
names.append(name)
msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()
print(msg)

maxval = max(results)
#print(maxval)
print('The best classifier is ' , maxval)
```

My output is:

```
LR: 0.552291 (0.021477)
SVM: 0.897305 (0.015317)
KNN: 0.884636 (0.016431)
NB: 0.609434 (0.026586)

The best classifier is  0.654986522911 NB
```

It was supposed to be SVM but how do I do this?

the first number after the name is the mean of the results, and the numbers in brackets are the standard deviation. When I run in my spyder python it will select NB(Naive Bayes) instead of SVM(Support Machine Vector).

Comment: You are taking max on the list of np.arrays ( model_selection.cross_val_score results in arrays), which is an invalid operation. Take the max on mean() of the results, and you will get SVM as result

Answer (score 1):

```
max_cross_val_score = max(cv_results.mean()) 
max_cross_val_score_classifier = models[cv_results.mean().index(max_cross_val_score)]
```

The best classifier is `max_cross_val_score_classifier` with `max_cross_val_score` as the max cross validation score.

Answer (score 0):

Value of the each element of list is an array. `model_selection.cross_val_score` returns an array. So you are taking max of arrays (which will give error in python 2.x).

Create list with mean of arrays, and you will get SVM as answer